# How to customize log output format in Catel?

Tags: c#, catel

We're using Catel 3.9 and `FileLogListener`. However the log format doesn't contain date nor thread id. Also the time format is in 12h and not 24h.

I couldn't find any way to customize the log format like in log4net. Is it possible or do I need to implement my own `FileLogListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all fixed in Catel 4+. For customization options available in 4+, check out the [latest docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/FileLogListener).

If you want to fix this in 3.9, you can override `FileLogListener` and customize the `FormatLogEvent` method or even implement your own `LogListener` (deriving from `LogListenerBase`).

If you are looking for documentation of older versions, please see the [version specific documentation](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL39/Writing+logs+to+disk).